# Автоматическая генерация web.xml

Tags: eclipse, servlet, java

В Eclipse создаю динамический веб-проект (`Dynamic web module version 3.0`), ставлю галочку на автоматическую генерацию `web.xml`. Создаю сервлет, где указывается `servlet mapping`. 
Сервлет запускается, все хорошо, все рады, только вот сам `web.xml` пустой (ну не совсем пустой, но сервлеты там не размечаются). В самом проекте есть раздел `Deployment descriptor: ServletProject`, где как раз таки и размечаются сервлеты, фильтры. В добавок к этому в самом сервлете добавляется аннотация вида `@WebServlet("/ServletName")`.

Собственно 2 вопроса:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы все связанное с сервлетами генерировалось в `web.xml`?
2. Почему Eclipse так делает? В чем плюсы/минусы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти аннотации были введены в рамках Servlet API 3.0 для (в частности) переноса конфигурации сервлетов из `web.xml` ближе к соответствующим классам. Возможно, есть другие плюсы, кроме облегчения `web.xml`, я о них не знаю.

Похоже, что настройки в Eclipse для генерации маппингов в `web.xml` для проектов, использующих Servlet API 3.0, нет.